# What's the meaning of put a life in your application?

Tags: phrase-meaning

When I learn the ruby on rails video, I saw a line code like below:

> Write Controller Code to put a life in your application.

I don't know the meaning of the `put a life`, could you explain what is the meaning ?

[image]

Comment: I think it means *to enliven*

Comment: @user178049 I think Joe Pinsonault's answer is reasonable.

Comment: Oh, OK. Im glad he helps you :)

Comment: It is not idiomatic or correct, though.  More normal would be "Put life in your application", because we're talking about life as a general phenomenon, not a specific person's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that they meant something like "to put life into your application". RoR controllers are where you put the business logic of your application. Where read from a database, transform your data, and then pass information to your Views. That's what I assume they meant by "put a life in" given the context

[This page](https://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/) might help you